# Query to select time of an intesection between points and a line

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm quite new to postgis and I have to query time when user tracks intersect checkpoints lines.

My DB design :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE locations (
  uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  user_uuid UUID NOT NULL,
  location GEOMETRY(POINT) NOT NULL,
  located_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE checkpoints (
  uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  line GEOMETRY(LINESTRING) NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to build a query that results in this type of rows :

```
| checkpoint_uuid | user_uuid       | located_at          |
| --------------- | --------------- | ---------------     |
| checkpoint_1    | user_1          | 2021-11-05 15:50:30 |
| checkpoint_1    | user_2          | 2021-11-05 15:51:10 |
| checkpoint_1    | user_3          | 2021-11-05 15:51:13 |
| checkpoint_2    | user_1          | 2021-11-05 16:12:30 |
| checkpoint_2    | user_3          | 2021-11-05 16:13:41 |
| checkpoint_2    | user_2          | 2021-11-05 16:13:48 |
```

I have multiple users emitting locations data with a time in table locations.
In table checkpoints I have a line for each checkpoint. Users will cross these lines at some time.

For the moment I can find the intersection point between the user run and checkpoints :

```
SELECT checkpoints.uuid, user_uuid, ST_Intersection(ST_MakeLine("location")::geography, line)
FROM locations, checkpoints
GROUP BY checkpoints.uuid, user_uuid, line
```

But I can't retrieve the time of this intersection. If I add located at to the select it will fail the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you just need a spatial join. With the function [`ST_Intersects`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) you can filter only the records that do intersect, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  chk.uuid, 
  loc.user_uuid, 
  loc.located_at
FROM locations loc 
JOIN checkpoints chk ON ST_Intersects(loc.location,chk.line);
```

Comment: I just tried this but it does not return any results. 
In fact user locations are not exactly on the checkpoint line. One user point is one meter before and the following is one meter after.
The intersection should be between the line made by all the user locations and the checkpoint line.

Comment: @ybert would a buffer around the point be an option for you?

Comment: I don't know. What are the pros and cons of a buffer around the point ?

Comment: @ybert could you take a look at the query in this fiddle? It might interest you https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=52dde3c0ada3415ee9843a99078daa8e

Comment: Wow it looks great. But now it seems it is a perfrormance problem. Iget an error :  lwgeom_intersection_prec: GEOS Error: InterruptedException: Interrupted!
I have actually 4 users with between 1k and 5k locations each.

Comment: @ybert are your geometries indexed? e.g. `CREATE INDEX idx_locations_location ON locations USING gist (location);`

Comment: Yes I added an index on the location field. But the error still the same.

Comment: @ybert the issue is that your'e creating the trajectory (linestring) in query time, and this operation is kinda expensive. Since trajectory data normally do not change, would it be an option for you to create the linestrings and store them in a table? It would speed up and simplify things a bit. Cheers

Comment: I can store  linestring in a table. I have to update these strings frequently based on new locations data stored on the server (It can be one location per second per user). I don't know if is ok to calculate linestring each time a new location is stored and then store the linestring.

Comment: @ybert that's indeed tough. An alternative would be to update the linestring directly (add new points) instead of storing each new point individually as a separated record. But as I am not familiar with your use case, it also may not apply. Also, you should use `point m` for that matter ;) Cheers and good luck

Comment: I will try to store directly Linestring with POINTM inside. Thanks, you helped me a lot ! :)

Comment: @ybert sounds like a good plan. It is always a good idea to do heavy lifting transformation beforehand to avoid overhead in query time. See this example with `ST_AddPoint`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f1a7851287808b2b242973b90ab54156